# g++ doesn't output any errors

Tags: c++, g++

Whenever I try to compile a c++ code with g++ on terminal, I can't seem to get g++ to output any error messages even though I am certain that there are errors that should be caught during compile time (such as syntax, reference types...).

I tried several ways such as this make file:

```
all:
    g++ -W -Wall -Werror main.cpp
```

All it does is output:

```
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

which isn't that useful, obviously...

Typing things like this:

```
g++ -W -Wall -Werror main.cpp
```

directly to terminal (without the make file) doesn't output any messages at all.

However this successfully outputs all of the errors while compiling:

```
cc main.cpp
```

My question is: how do I make g++ to output error messages so I can know where to correct my code?

Comment: If GCC doesn't output any errors, then there is no errors? Have you checked that a new `a.out` file is created? And that `cc` shows errors is because you use a C compiler to compile C++ code.

Comment: I am quite sure there are errors. I even purposely add mistakes to my code and it still doesn't catch any errors. And it doesn't output a.out

And well cc does catch the errors well for my C++ code

Comment: g++:
`i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)`
cc:
`Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0`

Comment: @StarShire Given what you are telling us, your `g++` installation seems to be shot. Can you compile and run C code with `gcc` (not `cc`, which is a symlink to the default compiler, here `clang/llvm`)? (btw, I don't know much about the Darwin architecture or mac hardware, but are you sure you really want to build for `i686` and not `x86_64` like `clang` is doing?)

Comment: @Thomas I ran a `main.c` code that simply outputs "Hello world" and `gcc` works as expected and outputs the `./a.out`. Actually I noticed that `g++` (for C++) and `gcc` (for C) successfully compiles and outputs `./a.out` when there are no errors. When I am certain that there are errors in my code, then no error messages are outputted and `./a.out` doesn't appear. That's my main problem I am having right now. And sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by the last bit you mentioned.

Comment: You should use `-Wextra` rather than `-W`. It should make no difference, but `-Wextra` is the preferred form. [See this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html) and search for `-Wextra`

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing - is it possible your terminal doesn't print `stderr`? Say, for example, it moves it to a log file or something?

Try running

```
g++ [whatever your arguments are] |& cat
```

(this is if you use tcsh)
or

```
g++ [whatever] 2>&1 | cat
```

if you use bash.

Answer (score 0):

Try something simple like this:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to output anything either. It feels like it's ignoring the command...

Comment: Could you post your main.cpp?

Comment: Also, `g++ --version`?

Comment: Well even if I purposely add random gibberish to my code that is not part of C++ syntax, no errors/mistakes are caught. It just outputs nothing like nothing happened...

Comment: `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)`

Comment: @StarShire: Try this: `echo '#error' > main.cpp ; g++ -c main.cpp` (copy-and-paste that exact command into your shell). If that doesn't produce an error message, then your `g++` is broken. (I'm trying to eliminate the possibility that you're not compiling the source file you think you are, or that it doesn't contain what you think it does.)

Answer (score 0):

Make reports an error when one of it's tasks returns non-0 status. If g++ silently returns non-0 - well, i suppose it's broken somehow. Check $? after you've run g++. Also, try g++ --version - will it report anything at all? Also you could run it under debugger, just to be sure.

Comment: I have a feeling that is the problem. And could you explain when you say "check $?"?
`g++ --version` outputs: `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)`

Xcode seems to work fine.

Comment: `g++ main.cpp; echo $?`; Also, check what your `cc` point to, if you say that it works fine. Try `gcc main.cpp` - it may point at different program in your installation. You could also check --version for cc and gcc - i don't like 'llvm' in your version string, but neither do i know OSX, so it could be just fine.

Comment: `g++ main.cpp; echo $?` outputs a `1`. How do I check where `cc` points to? `gcc main.cpp` doesn't output anything and gives me a `1` when I do `echo $?`.

`cc` version: `Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix`

Comment: So your 'cc' is actually clang. And your gcc seems to be broken. You could try running it under debugger (if you gave gdb - `gdb $(which gcc)`, then `r main.cpp`, maybe you'll see something - although it currently seems unlikely to me). But your gcc version is old, i think you should update it anyway, so probably trying to find exact problem here doesn't worth an effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a line like

```
#warning hello from here
```

(or perhaps `#error` instead of `#warning`) into `main.cc` near the beginning (perhaps as the first line).

If

```
gcc -Wall -v main.cc
```

don't give any output (notably no warnings or errors) that means that your `gcc` is broken. Perhaps type `/usr/bin/gcc` instead of just `gcc`

BTW, Apple don't like GCC (because they dont like its GPLv3+ license). Maybe it is worth your time to build [using e.g. `..../configure --program-suffix=-local`] and install a newer GCC (perhaps from the [released source](http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) tar ball of the compiler). Current version is 4.8.1!